# ngx translate angular 7 how to translate dynamic data comes from differents API's

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngx-translate

I'm facing a problem with ngx-translate! That's is I have 2 sperate API's with different languages so for example similar to this `http://example.com/api` and `http://example.com/fr/api/`

Now in ngx-translate I have to use `en/fr.json` files to translate my angular application! as I saw from the docs!

But now I need be using the data that comes from the both API's! it's already translated on the server!

> `http://example.com/api`
>
> `http://example.com/fr/api/`

So my question here how I do that?! as well keep using the `json files` as there some statics words in my app like `the application menu`

If there any other alternatives please don't hesitate to tell!

Comment: So, the APIs have no relation to the translation objects (the JSON structure that is normally in a translation file)? If I understand right, you need to fetch data from a localized API depending on the selected language, right?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Yes that's exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- Only 2 possible lang options: `["en","fr"]`
- Translations files are not fetched from the localized APIs. Instead, they reside in your project´s *assets* folder.
- On language change through ngx-translate, there is no need to *re fetch* data

You can create a service that *constructs* the correct API endpoint as follows:

```
@Injectable()
export class EnpointLocalizer {
  private readonly tokenMap = {'en': '/', '/fr/'}
  constructor(private readonly translate: TranslateService){}

  localizeJoin(sections: string[]){
   const {currentLang} = this.translate;
   return sections.join(this.tokenMap[currentLang] || '/'); 
  }
}
```

Then you could inject it where required and consume it as follows:

```
@Injectable()
export class FooService {
 private endpoint = ["http://example.com","api"];

 constructor(private http: HttpClient, private localizer: EnpointLocalizer){}

 fetch(){
   return this.http.get(this.localizer.localizeJoin(this.endpoint),...);
 }
}
```

Of course, there are different ways that you could implement that "localize" logic (eg. regex patter + replace). But for your use case I think this is a simple and clear start.

Answer (score 0):

use translate pipe for only those words `(some statics words in my app like the application menu)`

like

> {{ 'HOME.NAME' | translate }}

and remove translate filter from api data